# Looping through a dictionary and prinitng the keys, outputs a "None" value at the last itiration, why is that?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to understand why does this function print "None" at the end, even if the dictionary has only 3 keys.

```
def groups(group_dictionary):
    
    i = 0
    for group in group_dictionary:
        print(group)
        print(i)
        i = i+1


print(groups({"local": ["admin", "userA"], "public":  ["admin", "userB"], "administrator": ["admin"]}))
```

Output:

```
local
0
public
1
administrator
2
None #I don't understand this line
```

Thank you

Comment: The `question2answer` tag is only for a specific PHP framework. It has no place in a Python question.

Comment: Because your function return None

Comment: The none value is not a key for the dictionary rather it is the value returned by the function "groups". A function without an explicit return value returns None is python.

Comment: Your function prints but doesn't return anything. If you try to print a function that doesn't return anything, `None` will be printed, because a function that doesn't return anything implicitly returns `None`. So, your function is running and printing your dictionary just fine - there are no `None` keys. It's just that you're unnecessarily trying to print the result of the `group()` function.

Comment: Every Python function returns `None` if you don't explicitly return a value. So `groups()` itself returns a value of `None` and `print(groups())` prints `None`. You can fix this by calling `groups` on its own and skipping the outer `print` function.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the info, I didn't know.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got it now!

Answer (score 0):

It is printing the return value of `groups` function, which is None (no return statement).